# different ssl server configuration per path

Tags: apache, http, ssl, https, f5

Is it possible to have a different SSL configuration per url path in the same domain?  My dilemma is as follows:

I've been using SSLyze (https://github.com/nabla-c0d3/sslyze) and SSLLabs Server Test (https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/) to see whether a particular domain is configured correctly.  However, none of those tools goes down to a specific url path.

For example, if `test.com` has a particular SSL config and `test.com/app` has another particular SSL config, then those two tools would not be able to check test.com/app's configuration.  Is this a valid concern or are SSL configurations tied to the domain and cannot differ depending on the url path?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to have a different SSL configuration per url path in the same domain?

No, this is not possible. SSL/TLS is negotiated with a particular host and port. The server doesn't even receive the HTTP request, which contains the path, until an HTTPS session has been established.

> SSL configurations tied to the domain and cannot differ depending on the url path?

Correct. The domain / host plus the port. The path is part of the HTTP request, so it's actually "protected" by HTTPS.